# Swift create extension for textfield shadow code

Tags: ios, swift

I have multiple textfield but all the textfield have same shadow effects, I need to use extension for that shadow code and use it shortly in viewdid load.

below code I am using

```
//MARK - Email TextField
        email_textfield.borderStyle = .none
        email_textfield.backgroundColor = UIColor.groupTableViewBackground // Use anycolor that give you a 2d look.

        //To apply corner radius
        email_textfield.layer.cornerRadius = email_textfield.frame.size.height / 2

        //To apply border
        email_textfield.layer.borderWidth = 0.25
        email_textfield.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor

        //To apply Shadow
        email_textfield.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
        email_textfield.layer.shadowRadius = 1.0
        email_textfield.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero // Use any CGSize
        email_textfield.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor

        //To apply padding
        let paddingView : UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: email_textfield.frame.height))
        email_textfield.leftView = paddingView
        email_textfield.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.always
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create extension like this

```
extension UITextField {

    func applyCustomEffect() {
        self.borderStyle = .none
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.groupTableViewBackground // Use anycolor that give you a 2d look.

        //To apply corner radius
        self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.height / 2

        //To apply border
        self.layer.borderWidth = 0.25
        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor

        //To apply Shadow
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
        self.layer.shadowRadius = 1.0
        self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero // Use any CGSize
        self.layer.shadowColor =
            UIColor.lightGray.cgColor

        self.layer.sublayerTransform = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(20, 0, 0)
    }
}
```

And apply this effect like below

```
email_textfield.applyCustomEffect()
```

Comment: What about the let paddingView part buddy? @Jaydeep

Comment: self.layer.sublayerTransform = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(20, 0, 0) will make you padding